How to access and call my Provider from main.dart?
I received a push notification message from Firebase. I set a SharedPreferences variable called total_new_warnings with the new number.
I'm doing this inside the file main.dart.  I also want to call my provider to notify other part of the app is using this variable to update their value as well.
My problem, I'm still inside main.dart how can I call my provider from inside this file (main.dart)
//increase the warning counter
void newWarning() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int totalCounter = 0;
  int currentTotalWarnings = prefs.getInt('total_new_warnings') ?? 0;
  totalCounter = currentTotalWarnings + 1;
  prefs.setInt('total_new_warnings', totalCounter);

  //notifer
   WarningCounterProvider warningCounterProvider =
                    Provider.of<WarningCounterProvider>(context, listen: false);
   warningCounterProvider.setData(totalCounter);
}

I got an error because there's no context in main.dart in this part of the code:
      //notifer
       WarningCounterProvider warningCounterProvider =
                        Provider.of<WarningCounterProvider>(context, listen: false);
       warningCounterProvider.setData(totalCounter);

My question: How can I access my Provider and run the notifyListeners?

You could try moving newWarning to the App's build() method instead, or if you have a widget that gets called before everything else is initialised that would also be an option. I typically have an "init/loading" screen before pushing the appropriate screen.

Define them inside MultiProvider when declaring your provider, define its value with whatever you want.
runApp(MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<WarningCounterProvider>(create: (_) => totalCounter),
    //other providers
    Provider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
    Provider<AnotherThing>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
)) ;


Please could you expand a bit further your code to how can I use the function SomethingElse() and AnotherThing().  I just want to see your example on how to implement that.  Thanks so much.

Also, please could you show how can I access to my Provider from another screen.   I want to update the counter on the BottomNavigationBarItem.  What I want, is when I received a notification message from Firebase, then I'll increase the counter value on BottomNavigationBarItem.

I found this link, it's look like there's no way to do what I want. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

I use riverpod, so I don't have expertise in provider but you can indeed increment counter when you receive notification, if you checked firebase doc, it gives us few listener to us, you can pass the ref to these listeners, and increment that, but in your case where you only want to ser counter on main, I guess you want to set counter on intial Message right?, so wherever you are calling the initalMessage fn in app, just pass ref to it. For provider I guess you pass context not the ref. In riverpod we can pass WidgetRef.

And SomethingElse() and AnotherThing() are just basic fn, these fn just return some value which you are using in prvoider, like your counter in WarningCounterProvider.
